# Programmatically Interact with Old an Windows Software

Tags: data-recovery, database, forms, winforms

I'm using an old Windows software program (was used up to around 2006, probably was written a few years before then). It has data stored in it that is stored in a Microsoft JET engine - that's the most I could figure out about the technology it's written in.

I want to click on buttons there, inset and copy values in forms there, programmatically.

Is there a way to any of those things?

If more information is required from you to help me, what tools can I use to analyze the technologies behind this software?

My motivation is to just take relevant data out of the software - I couldn't manage to convert the database of the software (it uses custom file extensions for storing the data).

Comment: I would look into any export or backup function the program has. Most often there is a way to export the data out and that data usually can be converted into something you can actually work with. If that really is not possible, you'll have to settle for a macro recorder program which is going to be very tedious.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought of checking out export functionality. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @LPChip (in the comments above) which helped:

> I would look into any export or backup function the program has. Most often there is a way to export the data out and that data usually can be converted into something you can actually work with. If that really is not possible, you'll have to settle for a macro recorder program which is going to be very tedious. – LPChip Oct 22 '19 at 14:21